# controlling smoothness of css3 animation

Tags: css

I'm trying to animate a series of keyframes to give the illusion of movement. I want to change the background position on my html element to show a different frame over the course of a second with a second or so gap until it plays again.

Here is what I have - **http://jsfiddle.net/kSNWV/** (I've just done the `-webkit` flavour for now for testing purposes). This is the image I am trying to animate (a train going into a tunnel) - https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8kmm.png

My html:

```
<div id="train"></div>​
```

My css:

```
#train { width: 110px; height: 43px; border: 10px solid #454545;
background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8kmm.png) 110px 0;
-webkit-animation: train 2s linear 0s infinite normal; }

@-webkit-keyframes train {
    0%{background-position: 110px 0;}
    2%{background-position: 0px 0;}
    4%{background-position: -110px 0;}
    6%{background-position: -220px 0;}
    8%{background-position: -330px 0;}
    10%{background-position: -440px 0;}
    12%{background-position: -550px 0;}
    14%{background-position: -660px 0;}
    16%{background-position: -770px 0;}
    18%{background-position: -880px 0;}
    20%{background-position: -990px 0;}
    22%{background-position: -1100px 0;}
    24%{background-position: -1210px 0;}
    26%{background-position: -1320px 0;}
    28%{background-position: -1430px 0;}
    30%{background-position: -1540px 0;}
    32%{background-position: -1650px 0;}
    34%{background-position: -1760px 0;}
    36%{background-position: -1870px 0;}
    38%{background-position: -1980px 0;}
    40%{background-position: -2090px 0;}
    42%{background-position: -2200px 0;}
    44%{background-position: -2310px 0;}
    46%{background-position: -2420px 0;}
    48%{background-position: -2530px 0;}
}
```

​
Is it possible to have a css3 animation that just 'snaps' to each step without animating the transition in between? Also, how do I reset this animation without having it play in reverse (right now it is animating `background-position` of `-2530px` back to `110px` at the end).

Comment: Any reason you aren't using a GIF?

Comment: well is this you wanted? http://jsfiddle.net/kSNWV/2/

Comment: @AspiringAqib, I don't think he wants any easing where that the frames appear to be an animated picture.

Comment: @TylerCrompton - I need full alpha tranparency and there is more than one to do (the second train is 80 frames).

Comment: possible duplicate of [css3 animations frame by frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528868/css3-animations-frame-by-frame)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `step-end` timing function. Note that this omits the last keyframe. http://jsfiddle.net/kSNWV/3/

Comment: Nice, I can run with this. Didn't know about `step-end`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: For sake of thoroughness, *if* you were to want a slightly smoother transition but quite as smooth as what `linear` would give you, you can use `steps(n)` when n represents the number of steps between keyframes. `steps(1)`, `steps(1, end)`, and `step-end` are all equivalent and `steps(1, start)` is equivalent to `step-start`. Note that all solutions drop at least one keyframe.

Comment: I'm sure I will find uses for the rest at some point in the near future. Thanks again :)